# array modifier to build a virtual pipe organ? or should I look for scriptwriter?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I wish to build a virtual rank of pipe organ pipes. Starting with a mesh pipe and with an "array" modifier I hope to be able to scale and line the pipes up easily within specific parameters.

1. The pipes need to be made of separate but linked parts that can be scaled independently. The cone at the bottom of the pipe scales at a different rate than the main cylinder.
2. The spacing between the pipes can be set and locked...ex. always .5units apart.
3. Can select every other pipe in a rank remove it from the rank and have all pipes resume the input space between pipes.
4. I would like to find a way to link the pipes with an audio file and a hyperlink(don't even know if this is possible---essentially I would like the meshes to be linked to a database like a 3D image map)

Is this possible? Is there a freelance site one recommends to find someone who can customize the array modifier, or is there a workflow to achieve this efficiently with the present software for thousands of different pipes!!

Comment: The way you formatted you question makes people less likely to want to answer it, friend. Try pressing enter after each bullet number you want.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of parts and variables to your question.

You could easily create the organ pipes in Blender and use the array modifier to place it in your scene. The array modifier allows for some degree of variation between instances, like scale rotation, position, but it is limited in scope, and for more freedom between each arrayed tube you are probably advised to use non-arrayed duplicate clones of each object.
You could then scale each part individually and space it properly without affecting all other objects.

Blender has no hyperlinking functions built in, and what you are looking for is some sort of interactivity like a real time demo or application. The way I see it you could achieve this in a few different ways, but this is a really broad area with many different possible approaches and probably out of scope for this site.

1. The most basic way would be to render out an image of your organ pipes, and build some sort of image map or clickable interface layed out on top of it, possibly using either HTML+CSS or SVG or some other technology to your liking.
2. Use blender's built game engine and create a simple game application that consists of some basic logic that reacts to clicking the pipes and playing the corresponding sound.
3. Use [Blend4Web](http://www.blend4web.com/en/) which is an addon for Blender that allows to create interactive WebGL based applications with some basic interactivity options and create a web based demo that reacts and plays sounds when clicked on certain objects.

Comment: Thankyou Silverain and Ramos. I will look into the interactive applications you mention. As for scaling them individually I'd have to do this thousands of times. I have tried the array modifier using an empty as object offset. This scales the array nicely for other purposes but I'm wishing I could control it more. Is there a way of anchoring a vertex on the end of each pipe so that the scaling with the object offset doesn't affect the location of the objects? Can I do this with a constraint modifier?

Comment: Scaling is done based on the object's center, maybe you can move the object centre to this location instead, relative to its geometry so that scaling is preformed with a correct base point and doesn't seem to move the object.