# Animating tracing lines

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

Cristóbal Vila has made some amazing videos. I believe I read somewhere that he uses modo for this, but that is beyond the scope of my question. At the start of [his "Ishafan" video](https://vimeo.com/814808) he animates tracing a "circular", flat pattern and after that he traces the lines of a vault. I am curious about the following:

1. Is there a good, non-"do this a couple hundred times" way to do the 2D tracing?
2. Is there a way to (almost) automatically make the "moving fronts" light up more than the rest of the 2D tracing, like in the video?
3. Is there a good way to do the 3D tracing, without having to use a boolean modifier with a bunch of moving objects to gradually reveal the lines?

I hope these questions are not too generic, (like: how to model, light and animate a running medieval army or something)? Is using python maybe the best option? I would love to hear your opinions on this.

Comment: Please don't rely on external videos for people to understand what you want, always describe with words what you wish to achieve and post reference images when relevant. See if these help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73633/animate-branch-growth https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76551/synchronize-an-object-following-a-path-and-the-appearance-of-the-path/76563#76563 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/how-to-animate-winding-a-ribbon-onto-a-cylinder/76766#76766

Comment: aldo related:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52536/array-modifier-to-build-a-virtual-pipe-organ-or-should-i-look-for-scriptwriter and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/how-to-animate-multiple-lines/3184#3184

Comment: Thank you. The links were very helpful. I think a bevel will probably solve #1 and #3 and a "follow path constraint" will solve #2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3) You might get along with curves and bevel. Not sure if you can get nice corners as in the video though.
[image: Extrude along path]

Comment: Thank you kind person. This probably is what I need indeed :) At least it is a good start.